# Example for Facebook graph URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get my Meteor app to save user_birthday and email in MongoDB. All I am asking for is an example for a URL that queries Facebook Graph for user_birthday and email by providing a facebook user ID and the corresponding access token. The perfect answer would be a link were I just copy my user ID and access token and it gives me my email and my birthday.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the API call: `/me?fields=email,birthday&access_token=[your-user-token]`

> https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,birthday&access_token=[your-user-token]

Comment: thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed :)